# How can I solve this error when I install DevStack in CentOS?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, centos7, devstack

I try to install DevStack in CentOS, and I have finished these steps following this official website 'https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/'. But when I excute './stack.sh',after few minutes, it occurred problem like that:
[image]

So anyone can help me?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the error.

I just remove mysql from my os, then try to  run './stack,.sh' again.